# Selecting nearest pairwise match in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have an R data.table that is structured as follows:

```
> str(dat)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  26802896 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ id : chr  ...
 $ date1 : Date, format: "2011-12-15" "2012-11-02" ...
 $ date2: Date, format: "2010-08-15" "2011-01-04" ...
 $ row_name : chr  ...
```

My goal is to create a new variable `matching_row_name` with the row name of a row for which `date1-date2>0 days & date1-date2<30 days` stratified by `id`. In the case of multiple matches, I would like use the `row_name` of the `min(date1-date2)` for the matching variables. There are no ties.

I have made a reproducible sample `data.table` as follows:

```
latemail <- function(N, st="2012/01/01", et="2013/12/31") {
  st <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(st))
  et <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(et))
  dt <- as.numeric(difftime(et,st,unit="sec"))
  ev <- sort(runif(N, 0, dt))
  rt <- st + ev
}
set.seed(1)
date1=latemail(1000, st="2012/01/01", et="2013/12/31")
set.seed(2)
date2=latemail(1000, st="2012/01/02", et="2013/12/31")
set.seed(3)
ids=sample(letters[1:10],100,replace=TRUE)
dat=data.table(date1=date1,date2=date2,id=ids,row_name=seq(1:1000))
dat=dat[date1<date2]
```

It looks like this

```
> dat
                   date1               date2 id row_name
  1: 2012-01-01 18:01:58 2012-01-02 06:36:13  b        1
  2: 2012-01-02 03:10:54 2012-01-03 14:57:18  i        2
  3: 2012-01-02 04:51:47 2012-01-04 03:47:44  d        3
  4: 2012-01-06 17:24:37 2012-01-06 23:12:37  g        5
  5: 2012-01-08 22:20:21 2012-01-09 09:12:45  f        9
```

I have tried things like the following:

```
test_function=function(date1="date1",date2="date2"){return(which(as.numeric((date1-date2))==as.numeric(min(date1-date2))))}
dat=dat[,test:=lapply(.SD,test_function), by =id, .SDcols = c("date1","date2")]
```

to no avail.

The ideal output would be something like this (note i made up the value for row name 2 in this example):

```
                   date1               date2 id row_name matching_row_name
  1: 2012-01-01 18:01:58 2012-01-02 06:36:13  b        1   32
```

Or if there is no second date in the range, then

```
                   date1               date2 id row_name matching_row_name
  1: 2012-01-01 18:01:58 2012-01-02 06:36:13  b        1   NA
```

Comment: I think you meant `date2 - date1 > 0` and `date2 - date1 < 30`. Also `min(date2 - date1)`. It is also unclear what units 30 is: minutes, seconds? Note when you take `date2 - date1` the answer can be in different units so it is safe to use `difftime(date2, date1, units = 'secs)`.

Comment: thanks for these clarifying questions. I meant `days`, and you're totally right about the other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made several assumptions as some details were not clear from the questions. As there are no positive `date1 - date2` values, I took `date2 - date1`. Also I took minutes as time units. Then my answer is:

```
f <- function(date1, date2) {
  dd <- as.numeric(difftime(date2, date1, units = 'days'))
  id <- which(dd > 0 & dd < 30)
  n <- length(id)
  if(n >= 1) which.min(dd)
  else if (n < 1) NA_integer_
}
dat[, matching_row_name := row_name[f(date1, date2)], by = id]
```

In case of additional clarifications I will update the answer.

Comment: this is really nice use case for flexibility